# Returning the biggest three digit number

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I have to write the following method: 
it will return the biggest 3 digit number made out of 
d1,d2 and d3. d1,d2, and d3 are all single digits.

For example threeDigit(3,2,9) will return 932.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
public static int threeDigit(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if(d1>d2 && d1>d3 && d2>3)
        return d1+d2+d3;
    if(d1>d2 && d1>d3 && d3>d2)
        return d1+d3+d3;
    if(d2>d1 && d2>d3 && d1>d3)
        return d2+d1+d3;
    if(d2>d1 && d2>d3 && d3>d2)
        return d2+d3+d1;
    if(d3>d1 && d3>d2 && d1>d2)
        return d3+d1+d2;
    return d3+d2+d1;
}
```

But it just returns the sum of the three numbers. How can I get it to return back the numbers themselves?

Comment: I give you hint: math 101, if a b c are digits and they create number abc then abc = a* 100 + b * 10 + c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just change return statement.

```
public static int threeDigit(int d1, int d2, int d3) {
    if (d1 > d2 && d1 > d3 && d2 > d3)
        return d1 * 100 + d2 * 10 + d3;
```

and write others:)

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a `String` and then cast it to an `int` at the end when returning it

```
public static int threeDigits(int a, int b, int c){
    String finalStr ="";
    int max, mid, min;
    // Your tests
    finalStr += max + mid + min;
    return Integer.parseInt(finalStr);
}
```

**Note :**

I would use `>=` to simplify your tests. Imagine having three times the same digit.

Comment: You could try a different variable name since `final` is a Java keyword and your code is not compilable

Comment: @mr5 Thank you for the contribution

Answer (score 1):

You could use `StringBuilder` and `Integer#valueOf`:

```
public static int threeDigit(int... d1) {
    Arrays.sort(d1);
    StringBuilder numString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = (d1.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        numString.append(d1[i]);
    }
    return Integer.valueOf(numString.toString());
}
```

Or if you want to only use integers, you could follow this approach:

```
public int threeDigit(int d1, int d2, int d3) {
    // Populate an array with the numbers
    int[] values = new int[]{d1, d2, d3};
    // Sort the array
    Arrays.sort(values);
    // Initialize the variable that will be returned
    int result = 0;
    // Reverse loop through the array to get 
    // the largest number.
    for (int i = (values.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        // Ensure that each digit fits the single 
        // non-negative digit constraint
        if (values[i] > 9 || values[i] < 0) {
            // Throw an exception
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("Bad Value: " + values[i]);
        }
        // Use the index in order to determine place value. 
        // Example: 10^2 * 3 + 10^1 * 2...
        result += Math.pow(10, i) * values[i];
    }
    // Return the largest possible digit.
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best approach I've seen here, but there are three things:  you should error out if you get a digit that's bigger than 9 or less than 0 (as in, throw an exception), the order in which you do this addition doesn't matter (since they're individual powers and won't impact one another anyhow), and as far as variable naming conventions go, `result` and `values` are better choices IMO than `number` and `nums`.  Lastly, don't forget to explain *what* it is you're doing, as using words to describe this can help this answer transcend its original language.

Comment: @Makoto Thank you for the feedback. I changed the variable names and added documentation. I think that will better explain why I have the loop for adding the digits. The numbers are individual powers but their value is calculated according to the position within the array.

Comment: @Makoto You are right about the order, the loop could go forward or reverse since the values are not dependent upon each other.

Answer (score 0):

The + sign with integers will add the numbers.

The + sign with strings will concatenate them, the simplest way to convert numbers to string is as follows:

```
int i;
String s1 = "" + i;
```

You need to add a step between your if statement and your return statement that converts the digits into strings.